# Eclipse: enable/disable button in toolbar

Tags: eclipse, plugins, toolbar

In my plugin I created an editor and EditorActionBarContributor which adds some Actions to the editor. I added the actions to the context menu of the editor programmatically. In the `seletionChanged()` I control which actions should be enabled in the context menu depending on the state of the editor, e.g. selections or the type of the file.

Now I want to move those actions to the eclipse toolbar as well. For this, I created an extension for the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.editorActions` and added an action for each action in the editor, with an IEditorActionDelegate for each action, which gets the correspondent action form the editor and runs it.

I want to control the enable/disable the buttons in the toolbar for these actions like I do in the editor, but I have no idea how I can do that. For example, I want a button to be only enabled if there is text selected in the editor.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would consider using Eclipse [commands](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd.htm) instead. They are more cleanly separated so that you can have one place that indicates the command is enabled/disabled and then that automatically manifests in the menu/toolbar/bound keys, etc.

Also, Actions are effectively deprecated, as commands has been the preferred mechanism since about Eclipse 3.5.

Comment: You are right, i should migrate to Commands. Is there any tutorial on how to "transform" actions to commands? I couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: Not that I know of, but the Commands stuff is much easier, so if you read the help documentation you should be able to figure it out pretty quickly.